# Conditional execution and redirection in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I want something like this:

```
maybeexec command arg1 arg2 &> /logs/log
```

Where maybeexec is a bash function, like so:

```
maybeexec() {
  if ! ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "$*" > /dev/null
  then
    "$@"
  fi
}
```

So basically it checks if `command arg1 arg2` is already running, and if so, does not run it.

My problem, though, is that even if `command arg1 arg2` is already running and so `maybeexec` does not run it concurrently, `/logs/log` is still opened for redirection and will overwrite the existing `/logs/log`, which I do not want.

What's the most elegant way to solve this?  If possible, I'd like to keep calling `maybeexec` as I do now, since I use it to run many commands that all redirect output to different files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your function is trying to do or what your issue is with redirection. The file descriptor table cannot be modified externally after a process is started (except with GDB and other hacks).

Please use [proper process management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) instead of `ps` in scripts. This approach isn't good. To search for a process by name, you should use `pgrep`, but that should never be done in a script either.

See also: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex
and: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite your code a little bit. Make redirection inside the function, not outside. The target for the redirection is noe specified as the first argument of the function (later it will be removed with `shift`):

```
maybeexec /logs/log command arg1 arg2

maybeexec() {
  LOG=$1
  shift
  if ! ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "$*" > /dev/null
  then
    "$@" >& $LOG
  fi
}
```